# Image Preview before submit doesn't work in IE 9 and Safari 5.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, file-upload, safari

I'm currently trying to make an image preview on the client side of selected image, before the user clicks on a submit button.

I've found this approach here in the forum:

```
function selectedPhotoText(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#imagePreview')
                        .attr('src', e.target.result)
                        .width(240)
                        .height(149);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
    else {
        $('#imagePreview').attr('src', "../../Images/blqblq.jpg");
    }
}

<img id="imagePreview" class="img-border" src="../../Images/blqblq.jpg" alt="Selected Image"/>
```

and the file upload control:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="uploadPhotoDialog" onchange="selectedPhotoText(this)" runat="server"/>
```

This approach works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Opera. Is there any workarounds for IE and Safari?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It does not work since it is not supported: http://caniuse.com/#search=FileReader

Comment: @epascarello I've already seen that it's not supported. I'm looking for workarounds for IE and Safari

Answer (score 2):

Safari to 5.X.X and IE to 9.x.x doesnt support FileReader.
Look this.
http://caniuse.com/filereader